# Trouble saving userpic to UserProfile in Django: null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I'm trying to make it so a user can upload an avatar to their UserProfile, but I keep getting the following error:

```
IntegrityError at /~csihar/userpic
null value in column "user_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (4, null, userpics/image.jpg).
```

...with the first value incrementing by 1 each time I try to upload. I've attempted to instantiate the form with the user's current profile before saving, as well as excluding irrelevant fields from the modelform, but it still isn't working and I'm not sure what I'm overlooking. However, the image does get saved to my `MEDIA_ROOT` before the error occurs.

models.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django_resized import ResizedImageField

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    userpic = ResizedImageField(max_width=100, max_height=100, upload_to='userpics/')

class UserpicUpload(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        exclude = ('user','user_id')
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.template import RequestContext
from items.models import User, UserProfile, UserpicUpload
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def userpic(request,list_owner):
    current_user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    current_profile = current_user.get_profile()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserpicUpload(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=current_profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            newuserpic=UserProfile(userpic=request.FILES['userpic'])
            newuserpic.save()
        gohomeurl = "/~" + request.user.username
        return HttpResponseRedirect(gohomeurl)
    else:
        form = UserpicUpload()
        return render_to_response('userpic.html', {'listowner': list_owner, 'form':form}, RequestContext(request))
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class UserpicUpload(forms.ModelForm):
    userpic  = forms.ImageField()
```

template (userpic.html):

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block body %}
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
<p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
<p>{{ form.userpic.errors }}</p>
<p>{{ form.userpic }}</p>
<p><input name="submit" value="Upload" type="submit" />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Tried putting class UserpicUpload in your forms?

Comment: @FrantzdyRomain Could you clarify? I'm a bit confused what you mean since UserpicUpload is already defined in forms.py and is successfully being passed to the template as {{form}}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was going about it all wrong and was creating new profiles rather than adding to an existing one. The problem was fixed by replacing the following lines in views.py:

```
newuserpic=UserProfile(userpic=request.FILES['userpic'])
newuserpic.save()
```

...with this:

```
newuserpic=request.FILES['userpic']
current_profile.userpic=newuserpic
current_profile.save()
```

Now I'm having issues getting the pic to display properly on the user's home page, but that's a whole separate issue that probably has to do with my MEDIA_URL - at least the pic is getting saved properly now!

Answer (score 0):

In your view.py you have the following code:

```
if form.is_valid():
   newuserpic=UserProfile(userpic=request.FILES['userpic'])
   newuserpic.save()
```

but you do not seem to associate the new profile with a user, I suspect this is why the error is raised. Something like

```
newuserpic.user = request.user
```

...might do the trick. I'm posting this answer just by reading your code, so please be gentle :)

**EDIT:** If you want to edit the *existing profile* of the current user instead of creating a new one you should do the following in your view:

```
if form.is_valid():
   u_profile=request.user.get_profile()
   u_profile.userpic = request.FILES['userpic']
   u_profile.save()
```

We first access the user profile, then edit the userpic property and finally save it.

Comment: I tried that and got the error `duplicate key value violates unique constraint "items_userprofile_user_id_key"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id)=(1) already exists.` I think I may be going about things wrong, as I don't want to create a new profile, but add the image to an existing one.

Comment: If I understand correctly ou want to update the current user's profile, so I edited my answer to answer your new request